# Why is the random generation and array working together if I press ENTER between each loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

As long as I have the readkey in the code the end result is 7 different random loops (foreach). When I remove readkey I mostly get 7 identical numbers (foreach).

That led me to start experimenting with Task.Delay but it seems to make no difference. I thought it might be a timing problem as intemittently the first of the 7 random numbers would be different from the last 6.

I want the code to work in one sweep without me having to press a key. My apology if the format in this post is dodgy. I have bad experince of pressing ENTER in *this* input window.

```
int[] tray = new int[7];

        for (int i = 0; i < tray.Length; i++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 26);
            //Task.Delay(9000);
            tray[i] = randomNumber;
            Console.WriteLine("randomNumber {0} is {1} ENTER ", i + 1, tray[i]);
            //Task.Delay(9000);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        foreach (var number in tray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
```

Comment: because you create Random inside loop. move it outside loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Task.Delay(9000)` does not block. It creates a `Task` that is completed after (approx.) 9000ms. But you *don't* wait for that task to complete.
2. The `Random` class does not magically generate real random numbers, but takes numbers from a pre-defined pseudo-random number list. *Where in the list* it starts is depends on a seed passed to its constructor. You use the default constructor which uses a timestamp as seed.
   If you don't pause in your loop (via `Console.ReadKey()` or `Thread.Sleep(9000)` instead of `Task.Delay(9000)`), this timestamp is probably always the same so you always get identical "random" numbers.

To avoid these problems, declare your `Random` outside the loop's scope, so it's initialized once and does not repeat the same numbers:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < tray.Length; i++)  
    tray[i] = rnd.Next(1, 26);
```

---

More information about [pitfalls in random number generation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28548/Pitfalls-in-Random-Number-Generation).

---

And a (imo) more elegant way to generate an array of 7 random numbers:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] tray = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(i => rnd.Next(1, 26)).ToArray();
```

Comment: OK, That makes sense.

But how should I go about getting 7 random numbers to populate my array if I do not put them in a loop? 

I tried to put the random generator in a method and calling it but have the same problem.I ended up using Thread.Sleep but I am aware that it is not a good way.

Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: @Paladin by instantiating the `rnd` only once outside the loop as I and Habib suggested. Updated my answer.

Comment: Wow that was way out of my noobness.I see how I could have looked deeper in *.Range. Thanks again I have only been at this a short while as a student.

Comment: @Paladin if this solved your issue, you may mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: It is solved. Looking franticly do mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are intializing the `Random` inside the loop. Move the declaration outside of the loop and you should get *random* values. like:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < tray.Length; i++)
{
    int randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 26);
    //Task.Delay(9000);
    tray[i] = randomNumber;
    Console.WriteLine("randomNumber {0} is {1} ENTER ", i + 1, tray[i]);
}
```

When you have the `Random` inside the loop, it uses system clock for seed. Without `Console.ReadKey` each iteration would end up using the same seed because of very less work in the iteration. Thus `Random` (`rnd`) would end up using the same seed every time. Once your introduced `Console.ReadKey`, that will change the seed and because of that you were seeing different result.

One more thing, is that you tried `Task.Delay` but you didn't see any difference. The reason is that `Task.Delay`  doesn't block the thread, so there was no change in clock time for the next iteration. Just for the purpose of test, you can use :

```
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
```

Or

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

This will cause the thread to be blocked for almost a second and you will end up with different/random results.

Still the better approach would be to intialize `Random` outside the loop.